# Vuforia area target tracking problem after getting no-pos status -Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I've hit issue in Vuforia via Unity as block the camera view with my hand, i loose Area target tracking.
As I remove my hand from the camera, I'm unable to track the area target again.
I've searched for a solution on the Vuforia Package and I've added logs to Vuforia's code and i came across that the area target has a tracking status and the second i get a status "no-pos" i'm unable to find the area target anymore.

I would be happy to receive some assistance with my problem as Vuforia hasent been much hopeful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way to fix this issue...
When the area target pose change to "no - pose" , you can use the reset method of DevicePoseBehaviour of Vuforia and this method reset the "pose", you can do it using a button or everytime the status change to "no-pose".
this is my script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class PoseReset : DevicePoseBehaviour
{
    public void ButtonPoseReset()
    {
        Reset();
    }
}
```

good luck